# PyQt5 Получения свойства кнопки "Enabled"

Tags: python, pyqt5

Устанавливаю активность кнопки:

```
self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
```

Скажите, как мне правильно получить в дальнейшем это свойство, чтобы присвоить в переменную True либо False? Скажем что-то вроде:

```
x = self.pushButton.Enabled
```

Соответственно эта часть кода не правильная

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enabled-prop

```
x = self.pushButton.isEnabled()
```